# How to enable / disable any record in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to enable / disable any record in gridview ?

using mssql

I want in my gridview the following will appear ..

```
Name          Course         Year          Status  
Sam           MCA            2010          Enable
```

when i click on enable then record will be displayed in gridview and the enable button will convert into text disable... and when i click on disable then the record will be disable in gridview and enable button will appear ...

I want to use vb.net, asp.net (vb) to do that ...

Answer (score 0):

Use a Checkbox in a [TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx) or a [CheckBoxField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxfield.aspx) in your GridView to display the Enabled-State. Here is a Tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx